# How do I query wiktionary for all personal names?

Tags: names, wiktionary

Wiktionary can be downloaded [here](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/).

How can I extract all personal names? There's more than one category, so not sure how to go about that.

Edit: I need this information in a format that Excel can read (so csv or json would do). I also need to delete (or not extract) anything which isn't a personal name as the wiktionary dump is 8 gigs unpacked.

The information I want is:

- The name - Cecil
- IPA pronounciation (and alternative pronunciations) - /ˈsiːsəl/;/ˈsɛsəl/
- Translations:
  Basque: Zezilio
  Belarusian: Цэцылій m (Cecylij)
  Italian: Cecilio (it) m
  Latin: Caecilius m
  Polish: Cecyliusz (pl) m
  Portuguese: Cecílio (pt) m
  Spanish: Cecilio (es) m
  Ukrainian: Цецилій m (Cecylij)
- Pet forms (these are for the name James, as none are listed for Cecil):

  Jaime
  Jake
  Jambo
  Jamie
  Jay
  Jem
  Jemmy
  Jim
  Jimbo
  Jimmi
  Jimmie
  Jimmy
- Descendants:

> English: Jim (diminutive)
>
> English: Jimbo (diminutive)
>
> (jimbo) Hawaiian: Kimo
>
> (diminutive) English: Jamie, Jamey (diminutive)
>
> (diminutive) Chinese: 詹姆斯 (Zhānmǔsī) (transliteration)
>
> Cornish: Jammes, Jamma
>
> Danish: James
>
> Fijian: Semesa
>
> Icelandic: James
>
> Irish: Séamas, Séamus, Seumas
>
> English: Seamus, Shamus
>
> Manx: Jayms
>
> Maori: Hemi
>
> Samoan: Semisi
>
> Scottish Gaelic: Seumas
>
> English: Hamish
>
> Swedish: James Welsh: SiâmsEnglish: Jimmy, Jimmie, Jimmi, JimiHindi: जिम्बोEnglish: Jem (diminutive) English: JemmyEnglish: Jay

Including pronunciations in all languages.